# file system task error an error occurred with the following error message the device is not ready in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have an File System Task that copies a file from one directory to another. But i executing  package with different machine very first time I got device is not ready error message from file system tack component.

Any one guide me.

Comment: I guess something wrong with absolute relative paths in  File System Task

Comment: While executing second time without any changes.It's ran perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing package from **SQL Server Job** check credentials from which **SQL Agent Service** is running. If credentials is OK then it maybe network (DNS) or Active Directory issue.

Comment: I'm running only in the design mode .

Comment: You are using UNC path or network drive to access the file on different machine?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Zane in that case, where is the question? :)